# How to determine the region of integration after switching the order of integration in higher dimensions?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sobolev-spaces

I ran into this problem when I was reading the proof of the Sobolev imbedding theorem in Adams's book:
We let $\Omega_k$ denote the insection of $\Omega$ with a k-dimensional plane H, where $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a domain,let $\Omega_{k,\rho}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:dist(x,\Omega_k)<\rho\}$, and let u and all its derivativs be extended to be zero outside $\Omega$.Denoting by $dx^{'}$ the k-volume element in $H$,than why the following equality is right:
$$\int_{\Omega_k}dx^{'}\int_{B_{\rho}(x)}|D^{\alpha}u(y)|^pdy=\int_{\Omega_{k,\rho}}|D^{\alpha}u(y)|^pdy\int_{H\cap B_{\rho}(y)}dx^{'}$$

Comment: is the domain $B_\rho(x)$ or $x’$? or what is $x$?

Comment: Yes,$B_{\rho}(x)$ is a ball with center $x$ and radius $\rho$

Comment: No, I mean, is x the same as x prime? X does not appear on the right.  Only x prime

Comment: No,$x'$ is $k$ dimensions, and $x$ is $n$ dimensions

Comment: Can you give the page number it appears in Adams? Your integral equation is an equation of the form $$\int F(x,x’,y) dx’dy = \int G(x’,y)dydx’$$ which I am finding hard to understand.

Comment: Yes, it's in page $89$

Comment: Could you tell me the reference of this trick, I've been puzzled for a few days.